# New wiki tag content for the first time

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

In the Edit review queue, I encountered a lot new wiki tag edits. When I clicked on the wiki tags for more information. It did not find any information, so I assume they were newly created tags by a user.

My worry is the amount of content/information added by the user was very small. Most of the time it was just one or two lines along with Github link occasionally.

Few Links: [Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10756905), [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10756896), [Link-3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10756899), [Link-4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10756906), [Link-5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10756900), [Link-6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10757045)

How these type of new wiki tag edits should be handled?

My impression is that user should add at least one or two paragraph which explains little more about the tag.

Comment: Well, the big picture at the start is a no-go.

Comment: The same suggested-edits were also spotted by some regulars in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/27873425#27873425) room. We declined a bunch of them.